# Convert Sql Query of Last 50 minutes record into Linq Query

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

Sql Query:

```html
select Latitude,Langitude,Time from tblLatLang
where Time < GetDate()
and Time > (DateADD(mi, -50, GetDate()))
```

Sir I am new in Linq . I have the above SQL query and wants to convert it into Linq.The above query do fine work in SQL.

Comment: LINQ to what? e.g. LINQ to Objects, LINQ to Entities (if yes, what EF version, e.g. 6, Core etc.)

Comment: LINQ to Entities , .NET 4.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the equivalent LINQ to Entities query:

```
var query =
    from t in db.tblLatLang
    where t.Time < DateTime.Now
       && t.Time > DbFunctions.AddMinutes(DateTime.Now, -50)
    select new { t.Latitude, t.Langitude, t.Time };
```

As you can see, it's almost one to one translation. Just remember that LINQ `select` is after `from` :) Another detail specific for LINQ to Entities is that `DateTime.AddMinutes` method is not supported, so you should use [`DbFunctions.AddMinutes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions.addminutes(v=vs.113).aspx) canonical function instead.

Comment: Sir it give an error : The name 'DbFunctions' does not exist in the current context
also i install EF 6.3.1

Comment: You need `using System.Data.Entity;`

Comment: Yes sir , thank you very and very much. . . . . . .  .I am very thankfull to you and to all of stackoverflow members